# Formula for $P(X<Y)$ changing the order of integration

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If $X$ and $Y$ have a joint distribution $f(x,y)$, we have that
\[
P(X<Y) = \iint_{{x<y}}f(x,y)dxdy = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^yf(x,y)dxdy.
\]
Now, if I change the order of integration and use the definition of a marginal density I have
\[
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^yf(x,y)dxdy = \int_{-\infty}^y \left(  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x,y)dy \right) dx = \int_{-\infty}^y f_X(x)dx \stackrel{?}{=} F_X(y).
\]
However, this needs to be wrong, because it treats $Y$ as a constant and not as a random variable.

What am I missing here?

Comment: $P(Y>X)$ would be $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_x^\infty f(x,y)\ dy\ dx$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your error comes from how you reversed the order of integration. The region you are integrating $f(x,y)$ over is $\{(x,y) | x<y\}$, but simply swapping the integral signs as you've done integrates over the set $\{(x,y) | y<y\}$, presumably with two different $y$ meanings in the inequality.

Reversing the order of integration requires keeping the same integration region $\{(x,y) | x<y\}$, but restricting $y$ in terms of $x$.

$$\{(x,y) | x<y\}=\left\{(x,y) \left| \begin{matrix}-\infty<x<y,\\ -\infty<y<\infty\end{matrix}\right.\right\} = \left\{(x,y) \left| \begin{matrix}x<y<\infty,\\-\infty<x<\infty\end{matrix}\right.\right\}$$

$$P(X<Y)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^yf(x,y)\,dx\,dy=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_x^\infty f(x,y)\,dy\,dx$$

Comment: The variables $x$ and $y$ are bound to their integrals and cannot be referenced outside of that scope.   The inner bound variable may not appear in the domain limits of the outer integral; rather it is *always* the outer bound variable that restricts the inner integral's domain.